# GraphAPIError: (#500) Message contains banned content

Tags: facebook

I have encountered a GraphAPIError: (#500) Message contains banned content problem today when I use GRAPH API (via python) to POST URLs (even post http://www.google.com failed, but if I post it directly through my facebook page, it works)as comments. It used to working correctly.

Does anyone encounter the same problem or know how to solve that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this issue - seems that if an FB user who is NOT validated with FB (hasn't given FB their cell phone etc) comments on some posts, they can get a 500 error. Once validated the error doesn't happen